# Comparing elements in a array using equalities (Java) slot machine

Tags: java, arrays

So what im trying to do is take the randomly generated elements in my array and commpare them to make sure all three are the same.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Random;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in);
        int slots[] = new int[3];
        Boolean play = true;
        String playAgain;

        System.out.println("Welcome to the Simple Slot Machine!");
        System.out.println("Press Enter to spin the wheels...");

        Reel(slots);
    }

    public static void Reel(int[] slots) {
        Random rand = new Random();
        int num1 = 0;
        int num2 = 0;
        int num3 = 0;
        int i;


        for( i = 0; i < slots.length; i++) {
            slots[i] = rand.nextInt(10);   
        }
    
        num1 = slots[0];
        num2 = slots[1];
        num3 = slots[2];

        if (num1 == num2 && num2 == num3) {
            System.out.print(slots[i] + "... you win");
        }
        else if (num1 != num2) {
            System.out.print(slots[i] + "... you lose");
        }
    
    }
}
```

So far I've been able to get it to randomly generate numbers
and I've figured out how to attach one of each three elements to three variables
but once I make the condition where if num1 not equal to num2 the code breaks

i need it to say 777... WINNER! or 546... LOSER!
wanna get this working before i work on the loop

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "code breaks", but it's not doing anything after that check, so, yes, the program will end

Comment: There is no code after that check in your code. So what are are you expecting it to do after that?

Comment: it says index 3 out of bounds or it just doesn't print anything at all im pretty new to coding so im just stuck

Comment: i need it to print 546... NOT a winner. or 777... WINNER!

Comment: Slot[i] throws exception after finishing loop i is 3

Comment: so what should i do to fix it and still get the results i want? should i get rid of the slot[i] and just use System.out.print(num1+num2+num3) ?

Comment: Or `Arrays.toString(slots)`. Not sure why you're holding onto `i` at all. It should be declared inside the `for` parentheses.

Comment: Also, can't you just use an `else`? Why are you specifically checking if the first two elements match?

Comment: @shmosel i tried that once but when i first started the code it just told me i had to use else if so i just kept using it

Comment: It told you? Who's it?

Comment: Also, what's the point of the variables? And why initialize them to 0?

Comment: @shmosel the java error system and once i added it, it worked, also i added variables because i want to compare and it didn't work with just using slots[1] or slots[0] and when i printed to see what was wrong the values showed up as 0, so i decided to take the values from the array and print them to varibles and compare them

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason you were getting the error in your code is because you are using `slots[i]` in your print statement but by the time it comes out of the for loop. It would have already incremented one more than your array size. You can just declare the `i` within the for loop and print using `Arrays.toString(slots)`. Also, you have already checked if all three values are equal in your first `if` statement. So you don't need `else if` statements. You can just put an `else`. Here is the modified code

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Random;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in);
        int slots[] = new int[3];

        System.out.println("Welcome to the Simple Slot Machine!");
        System.out.println("Press Enter to spin the wheels...");

        Reel(slots);
    }

    public static void Reel(int[] slots) {
        Random rand = new Random();
        int num1 = 0;
        int num2 = 0;
        int num3 = 0;


        for(int i = 0; i < slots.length; i++) {
            slots[i] = rand.nextInt(10);   
        }
    
        num1 = slots[0];
        num2 = slots[1];
        num3 = slots[2];

        if (num1 == num2 && num2 == num3) {
            System.out.print(Arrays.toString(slots) + "... you win");
        }
        else {
            System.out.print(Arrays.toString(slots) + "... you lose");
        }
    
    }
}
```

If you need to print the array as you want, you can just create your on method to print it.

```
public static String arrayToString(int arr[]) {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for(int i=0; i<arr.length; i++) {
            sb.append(arr[i] + " ");
        }
        return sb.toString();
}
```

You can customize the append method to how you want the elements to be appended. This will print without the commas and other stuff.
You can call it using `System.out.print(arrayToString(slots) + "... you lose");`

Comment: pretty funny how you kind of post this as soon as i figured something out but i tried to use Arrays.toString but i didn't like how it looked with the commas and bracket and as ive never used it i didn't know how to change it, but i will keep this in mind for the future

Comment: @MountDew Accept the answer if it was useful to you. I have edited and added how you can print without commas or however you want

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.Scanner;

import java.util.Random;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in);
        int slots[] = new int[3];
        int num1 = slots[0];
        int num2 = slots[1];
        int num3 = slots[2];
        Boolean play = true;
        String playAgain;


        System.out.println("Welcome to the Simple Slot Machine!");
        System.out.println("Press Enter to spin the wheels...");

        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        scanner.nextLine();

        while (play) {
            Reel(slots);
            System.out.print("Do you want to spin again? (Y/N)");
            playAgain = scnr.nextLine();

            if (playAgain.equals("Y")) {
                continue;
            }
            else if (playAgain.equals("N")) {
                System.out.println();
                System.out.print("Come back soon!");
                play = false;
            }
        }

            

        

    }

        
    


    public static void Reel(int[] slots) {
        Random rand = new Random();
        int num1 = 0;
        int num2 = 0;
        int num3 = 0;
        int i;


        for( i = 0; i < slots.length; i++) {
            slots[i] = rand.nextInt(10);
            // System.out.print(slots[i]);
        }
        // System.out.print("... ");
        
        num1 = slots[0];
        num2 = slots[1];
        num3 = slots[2];


        if (num1 == num2 && num2 == num3) {
            System.out.println(num1 + "" + num2 + "" + num3 + "... you win, JACKPOT");
        }
        else if (num1 != num2 && num2 != num3) {
            System.out.println(num1 + "" + num2 + "" + num3 + "... you lose");
        }
        else if (num1 != num2 && num2 == num3) {
            System.out.println(num1 + "" + num2 + "" + num3 + "... you win");
        }
        else if (num1 == num2 && num2 != num3) {
            System.out.println(num1 + "" + num2 + "" + num3 + "... you win");
        }
        else if (num1 == num3 && num2 != num3 && num2 != num1) {
            System.out.println(num1 + "" + num2 + "" + num3 + "... you lose");
        }
        



        

    }
}
```

Even though my code is probably still bad, but after following the advice from some of you, I was able to get this code to work, or well, for what the teacher want the code to look like.

Comment: some hints: 1) there is no need for the array in `main`, as parameter to `Reel`, and as local variable in `Reel` - the array is not used, but for size, which is hard-coded; 2) no need for `continue;` in that loop; 3) the last condition will never be evaluated to `true`, that is already *part* of the second one; 4) the logic is kind of strange: if the first and second numbers are equal (`112`) you win, if the first and the last are equal(`121`) you lose; 5) naming convention: method names start with lower-case letter; 6) so many empty lines.... (and *incomplete* code formatting)

Answer (score 0):

The [Answer by softwareguy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/78184511/642706) correctly identifies the problem with your incorrect usage of the incremented `i` counter variable. Another nuance there is that commonly programmers define and access the counter variable of a `for` loop only *within* the loop, not outside of the loop as you did. Your code would raise eyebrows in the real world.

Also, I can address a few other issues.

First of all, lose the `int` variables. You already have the array of `int`  values, so the `int` variables are redundant.

Secondly, your logic could be simplified. Since you have only three possible values (three reels on a [slot machine](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slot_machine)), you have three kinds of situations: match all 3, match any two (3 possible combos), and no match. So a total of four tests plus a “else”.

By the way, “slot” refers to the coin drop. The three spinning wheels are known as *reels*.

```java
if ( reels[0] == reels[1] && reels[1] == reels[2] ) // Match all 3. 
{
    // Jackpot
} 
else if ( reels[0] == reels[1] )  // Match 2 (left side). 
{
    // Win
}
else if ( reels[0] == reels[2] )  // Match 2 (outside). 
{
    // Win
}
else if ( reels[1] == reels[2] )  // Match 2 (right side). 
{
    // Win
}
else                              // Match none. 
{
    // Lose
}
```

In a slot machine, we care about each possibility separately because we have to identify which of the reels match on our game display.

---

The common random generator is predictable, so not appropriate for a slot machine. Use a [cryptographically strong random generator](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographically_secure_pseudorandom_number_generator).

```
SecureRandom secureRandom = SecureRandom.getInstance( … );
```

See [article at Baeldung.com](https://www.baeldung.com/java-secure-random). See [*JEP 356: Enhanced Pseudo-Random Number Generators*](https://openjdk.org/jeps/356)

---

By the way, in more advanced Java, you can replace your `for` loop with use of an [`IntStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api//java.base/java/util/stream/IntStream.html).

```
int[] reels = secureRandom.ints( 3 , 1 , 10 ).toArray() ;
```